# Downloaded image gets resized

Tags: android, android-layout

I am downloading an image from the internet which has the following dimensions: 128px x 128px
After the download the image is used as the background of an `ImageButton` but when the button is displayed, the image is smaller than it was before it was downloaded. For the download i use an `AsyncTask` ... here is my code:

```
public class ImageDownloaderButton extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageButton> imageButtonReference;

    public ImageDownloaderButton(ImageButton imageButton) {
        imageButtonReference = new WeakReference<ImageButton>(imageButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        url = params[0];
        try {
            if (url.equals("")) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            result = null;
        }
        if (imageButtonReference != null) {
            ImageButton imageButton = imageButtonReference.get();
            if (imageButton != null) {
                if (result != null) {
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(result);
                } else {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimageavailable);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (imageButtonReference != null) {
            ImageButton imageButton = imageButtonReference.get();
            if (imageButton != null) {
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimageavailable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The codesnippet where the download is startet:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
ImageDownloaderButton downloader = new ImageDownloaderButton(imageButton);
downloader.execute(supp.getPicture()); //the picture is the url
imageButton.setOnClickListener(createOnClickListener(supp.getId()));
```

and finally here is the xml file which contains the `ImageButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/icon_with_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/icon_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/icon_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColorHighlight="#656565"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Can anyone explain to me why the image is resized?** The image (noavailableimage) that is shown while the AsyncTask is downloading is 128x128px and this one is shown in the correct size.

Screenshots:

[image: aphotheke]
[image: baecker]

Emulator:

[image: mainmenu]
[image: supplier]

Comment: How do you know its smaller? It appears smaller or you checked the  dimensions manually.

Comment: It's smaller because the "No image available" is at correct size :D

Comment: I added some screenshots and the images. As you can see the "no image available" picture is bigger than the "bäcker" image whereas both images have the same dimensions. The only difference is that the "no image available" picture is loaded from the drawable folder and the "bäcker" picture is loaded from the internet. I'm going to check the exact dimensions of both images now.

Comment: The dimensions were correct. But the method i used filled the buttons ImageView instead of its background. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before, instead of using the BitmapFactories decode method - try the using the Drawable class e.g.

```
URL url = new URL("some address");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(connection.getInputStream(),"src");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i use the Drawable.createFromStream the image is even smaller :/ [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/MHNjI)

Comment: What happens when instead of using "imageButton.setImageBitmap(result);" you use "imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(result)" ?

Comment: Yeah that worked. Seems as the setImageBitmaps only uses the buttons Imageview whereas setImageResource uses the Background! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this before you set the bitmap:

```
imageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: No that didn't change anything. Thanks for the try.

Comment: Try logging the w, h and scaling of the bitmap you get from decodeStream(..)

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that the image you are going to set is 128x128 size then set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `ImageView` to 128px.

Comment: I don't know it in advance, it was just for demonstration. I added some screenshots.