# downloaded images are resized automatically

Tags: android, menuitem

I download images from my server and save them using this code:

```
private void downloadImages(String[] images, String fileName){

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

        try {
            url = new URL(images[i]);

            String outputName = i+fileName;

            input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            output = activity.openFileOutput(outputName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            int read;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = input.read(data)) != -1){
                output.write(data, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            if (input != null)
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and this works just fine.

the problem is that when i read them to show them on `ImageButton` or `MenuItem` they are automatically resized.

when I pull the images out of the emulator, I find their sizes are correct.
the same behavior on each device that i used for testing.

I read the images using this code:

```
private Drawable[] readMenuImages(){   

    Drawable[] drawable = new Drawable[myJSONObject.getMenuItems().length]; 

    for(int i=0 ; i < myJSONObject.getMenuItems().length ; i++){


        try {
              drawable[i]=Drawable.createFromStream(activity.openFileInput(i+activity.getString(R.string.menuItemImgarabicfilename)), "ImageStream");



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }          

    return drawable;
}
```

I actually can not understand what's going on or how to fix this.

I have visited this thread [Downloaded image gets resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194079/downloaded-image-gets-resized) but it didn't help.

thank you for your help.